# Is there a reason why my GUI builder doesn't match the reference images on codenameone's website?

Tags: codenameone

I'm working on the front end for an app in my CS class and I want to use the new GUI builder since previously I've been using the old one. I looked up videos on how to use the new builder and realized that the builder in the tutorials doesn't match what's on my screen making it hard to work with. Is there anything I can do to fix this or should I just adjust to the different layout?

CodenameOne example:

[image]

My example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are more options and more features but if you'll look at the actual buttons within the UI you will notice that they are identical. Once you place components in (which you drag from the right side) you will see a UI that's similar to the one in the first picture. Notice you need to click on the accordion in the right side to expand it.

Comment: I added a couple of buttons but nothing changed. I also tried creating a new form on a friend's computer and faced the same issue.

Comment: When you select the button you will notice the property selection options on the bottom left will appear. You will also notice the tree in the top right filling out. I don't really understand the problem, which difference between the UI's bothers you?

Comment: If you look at the Codenameone example, you'll see that the white box is in the center of the gray while in my example the box takes up the entire gray space and I can't change it. Is there a way to do so because if I'm trying to follow a tutorial that tells me how to use a builder but my builder doesn't look or work like the tutorial then I can't learn how to use it.

Comment: Drag the button on the bottom right. Drag it up and to the left diagonally. There's less wasted space in the newer version.

Comment: Here's a link to a video of me following your instructions. Am I pressing the wrong button because it's not matching the Codename One example? [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S9zHcSU_wORYRRuoBfxUCjOUwd8nkum0/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What's not matching??? This is exactly as it should be. Do you expect the UI built during the whole example to suddenly appear?

Comment: I just want to know how to get the white form centered in the gray screen since moving the accordion doesn't do that. The [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TktC5xFBVTw) I watched starts with the white screen centered so I want to know if I could have it that way. I'm not asking about making the form itself but how I can have it match the starting point.

Comment: It was never centered. There was just a lot of gray padding in the side which is no longer there. It was wasted space which is pretty significant in smaller monitors/laptops.